# How to pluralize a symbol in Ruby (on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pluralize

This works, but looks a little bit ugly:

```
s = :shop
s.to_s.pluralize.to_sym   # => :shops
```

Is there a nicer way to pluralize a `Symbol` ?

Comment: No, because Symbols are not meant to be altered(they are immutable).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pluralize a `String`, which represents actual text. `Symbol`s are a bit more abstract.

So, by definition, no. However, perhaps you could open up the Symbol class definition and add:

```
class Symbol
  def pluralize
    to_s.pluralize.to_sym
  end
end
```

Then, you can just call:

```
:shop.pluralize # => :shops
```

Answer (score 6):

Nope, that's the way.

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable altering Ruby's classes, then this works:

```
class Symbol
  def pluralize
    self.to_s.pluralize.to_sym
  end
end
```

I have yet to find a more elegant solution, although I suspect if there was, it would probably just be Rails implementing something similar to what I have above.